# CodeIgniter Date or DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have one problem, which I can not resolve and have no idea where is mistake
One I create a tabel called posts and in codeigniter create a form Posts, after createing all post I want to display posts in index.php and I have table called
Date of departure, and date of return. One i create post date looking good but when I display in my index.php it's look like 0000-00-00 00:00:00
In begginig data type was Date, now i change to be DateTime but nothing happend, same problem 
Maybe I make mistake in my JS script
Any comment ?

**My script**

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: Did you check in your database?? If it is actually storing the date you selected or it is storing 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Yeah, it's storing the same 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in db

Comment: Then problem lies in your insert query. Fix it and your problem will get solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your field in MySQL is Date-time it aspects proper format before saving in database.

So convert string to date time format in php using.

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($string));
```

Or you can do the same in Datepicker

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            var h = d.getHours();
                h = (h < 10) ? ("0" + h) : h ;

                var m = d.getMinutes();
            m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m ;

            var s = d.getSeconds();
            s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s ;

                datetext = datetext + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
        },
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr8wd04n/) for datepicker

**Note** if you want date only in MySQL field the omit hour min sec part of conversion