# I only getting Year that from HTML input type="date" to Database

Tags: php, database, html, date

this the code I used to get `Date` to my database and I getting the `Year` only to the database. what change I need to get `dd/mm/yyyy` to my Database

```
<?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","home_ac");
    if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Error While Connecting Database");
    }
    $date = ($_POST['date']);
    $query= "INSERT INTO `sample`(`id`, `date`, `currency`) VALUES (NULL,$date,'$date')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query)

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45781679/3898339) use `strtotime` and  change datatype of table column to Date

Comment: You should share your table's column types. Where do you want to store the date and year? In the same column or separate? It matters a lot to answer your question.

Comment: My Column datatype is datetime

Answer (score 1):

This example will display an input date box, ideally:

```
<label>Datetime:
<input type = "datetime"-local />
    (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm, such as 2012-01-27T03:15)
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['date'])){
$date = $_POST['date'];
 }
```

Also your query to the database should be formatted as such (assuming your ID is auto incremented):

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO tablename(date) 
 VALUES('{$date}')
```

Have your database formatted to accept the DATE format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the date you are trying to insert is in the correct format.  This is assuming

- your user enters a date like `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` - MySQL wants `yyyy-mm-dd`
- your `date` field is a `date` type, not `datetime` or `timestamp`

You can do this to convert:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'home_ac');
$date = $_POST['date'];
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));  //Would convert mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yy, etc. into yyyy-mm-dd for you.

if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Error While Connecting Database");
};

$query = "INSERT INTO `sample`(`id`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$date');";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Your initial query included a field, `currency`, that I did not include as you didn't have it in your html as a field a user would enter.  I'm guessing you have a valid password for root (your connect didn't include it and no root password is a bad thing)

You should also make sure you are validating that your user is entering a valid date, etc.

You may want to reconsider your table layout as **date** is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).  You can use it but you have to make sure to always enclose it with a backtick.